# Reference of a MongoDB database object

Tags: php, mongodb

I want to collect the names of the databases that a MongoDB instances sees. I am using the following in this effort:

```
Thread Safety enabled in PHP7
PHP 7.0.2 (cli) (built: Jan  6 2016 13:00:05) ( ZTS )
MongoDB shell version: 3.2.1
MongoDB PHP Library 1.0
```

In the below code I can see a list of the databases and their properties but I am unable to collect the names of the database as the foreach loop progresses.  I have tried variations of:

```
$databaseInfo->name;
$databaseInfo->[‘name’];
```

I do not know how to point to the name field in this database object that I want to collect.  Here is the code:

```
<body>
    <h1>Count and Name the databases!</h1>
    <?php
    // Bring in personal tools.
    include_once 'utilities/tools.php';

    // This path should point to Composer's autoloader
    require_once __DIR__ . "/vendor/autoload.php";

    // Find if we can connect to a Mongo instance
    $client = new MongoDB\Client;
    if ($client) {
        echo (breakLeft("Made a connection"));
    }

    echo (breakLeft('$client = '));
    var_dump($client);
    echo (rowDivider());
    // Find all the Databasses on this Mongo instance
    // Count databases
    $i = 0;
    /* listDatabases() returns an iterator/or cursor of MongoDB\Model\DatabaseInfo objects */
    foreach ($client->listDatabases() as $databaseInfo) {
        echo(breakLeft("database count = " . ($i + 1)));
        var_dump($databaseInfo);
        $i++;
    }
    echo (breakLeftRight("Total count of database = " . $i));
    ?>
</body>
```

Here is what the object looks like?

```
 database count = 1
    C:\NetBeansWorkPlace\mongoDB_overview\mongoGateway.php:39:
    object(MongoDB\Model\DatabaseInfo)[4]
    public 'name' => string 'databaseName' (length=12)
    public 'sizeOnDisk' => float 83886080
    public 'empty' => boolean false

    database count = 2
   C:\NetBeansWorkPlace\mongoDB_overview\mongoGateway.php:39:
   object(MongoDB\Model\DatabaseInfo)[7]
   public 'name' => string 'db' (length=2)
   public 'sizeOnDisk' => float 83886080
   public 'empty' => boolean false
```

Thanks!

Comment: According to this http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-php-library/api/class-MongoDB.Model.DatabaseInfo.html  you should be able to say $databaseInfo->getName().  Sorry, but I can't test it because I am using a different mongo driver for PHP.

Comment: That works.  Thanks for the answer and also for the link.  Also tell me what other driver is available for mongo and PHP except the older PHP driver.

Comment: Unfortunately it is an older driver.